# Why would TwoWay binding not update UI element?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, telerik

Something so very simple but I am pulling my hair out over it.

I am using mvvm Light to create a view model and in the view I have a property that I am binding too.

```
private TimeSpan _eventDuration
public TimeSpan EventDuration
{
  get { return _eventDuration; }
  set 
    {
      _eventDuration = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("EventDuration");
    }
}
```

Very simple and not complicated. Now in the UI I have a grid and on this grid I am using a `telerik` control called `RadTimeSpanPicker`. This control is bound to the above property like so.

```
Value={Binding EventDuration, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Now when I run my code and change the value of my RadTimeSpanControl in the UI and I see the change occur on the EventDuration property as it should.

My Problem is that if I change the property, the UI does not update.

So, just to clarify. 
UI, I change the timespan to `00:00:16` (that's 16 seconds). I see the EventDuration property change. I then do `EventDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);` and i see afterwards that the property is set but the UI still shows `00:00:16`

UPDATE: Problem Solved
I had my TimeSpanPicker set to minimum value of 0:0:1 (1 second) so when trying to assign a TimeSpan of 0 seconds the UI part it just ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

```
So, just to clarify. UI, I change the timespan to 00:00:16 (that's 16 seconds). I see the EventDuration property change.
```

Typo maybe?!
EventDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

Answer (score 0):

It seems to works for me:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <telerikInput:RadTimeSpanPicker Value="{Binding EventDuration, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="radTimeSpanPicker"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding SetToNow}" Content="Set To Now" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand SetToNow { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        this.SetToNow = new RelayCommand(SetToNowAction);
    }

    private TimeSpan _eventDuration;

    public TimeSpan EventDuration
    {
      get { return _eventDuration; }
      set 
        {
          _eventDuration = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("EventDuration");
        }
    }

    private void SetToNowAction()
    {
        this.EventDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    }
```

Comment: I found the problem, one of those stupid things that you miss when over analysing everything.